# select query with limit and offset nondeterministic?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I heard select queries that use a limit turn nondeterministic. I tried a simple query several times using limit and offset, and got the same results each time. Why is that?

Comment: It might related to caching, same query that's cached will return same result. Try turning off temporarily [USE_CACHED_RESULT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#use-cached-result)

Comment: As well as the caching issue, it's likely that the same query will access the same data in the same way and therefore you see the same result each time - but this is not guaranteed and hence the result is non-deterministic

Answer (score 0):

If a user repeats a query that has already been run, and the data in the table(s) hasn’t changed since the last time that the query was run, then the result of the query is the same. However, this is not guaranteed though the factors listed in the below link are met and hence non-deterministic.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-persisted-results.html#retrieval-optimization